# Como quebrar linha dentro do <textarea>

Tags: php, html

Preciso trazer a listagem de pessoas dentro de um `textarea` ou alguma alternativa similar.

Estou trazendo dessa forma:

```
<textarea rows="5" name="pergunta4">
<?php foreach($avaliadores as $avaliador):?>
<?php echo($avaliador['nome']);?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</textarea>
```

Mas os nomes dos avaliadores acabam vindo sempre um ao lado do outro ou então em espaços aleatórios.

Comment: Tente: `<?php echo($avaliador['nome']).'<br>';?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o `\n` para quebrar a linha dentro do `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea rows="5" name="pergunta4">
<?php 
    foreach ($avaliadores as $avaliador) {
        echo $avaliador["nome"]."\n";
    }
?>
</textarea>
```

**Exemplo:**

```
<textarea rows="5" name="pergunta4">
<?php 
    $avaliadores = array();
    $avaliadores[] = array("Id"=>"1", "Nome"=>"Caique");
    $avaliadores[] = array("Id"=>"2", "Nome"=>"Suporte");

    foreach ($avaliadores as $avaliador) {
        echo $avaliador["Nome"]."\n";
    }
?>
</textarea>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Outro exemplo:**

```
<textarea rows="5" name="pergunta4">
<?php 
    $avaliadores = array("Caique", "Suporte", "Renan", "RBZ");
    foreach ($avaliadores as $avaliador) {
        echo "$avaliador\n";
    }
?>
</textarea>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]